# C# how to make a function that can return either child or parent class

Tags: c#

Not sure if I made it clear on the title. What I want is this:
There is a parent class:

```
public class parent  
....
```

And a child class:

```
public class child : parent  
....
```

Now I need a method that can return either:

```
List<(what goes here?)> GetSomeValue(string id, boolean needChild) {  
  ......  
  if (needChild)  
    return BuildChildResult(id);  
  else  
    return BuildParentResult(id);  
}
```

Is this something possible to do?
What should be in the bracket?

Comment: Why couldn't I identify code blocks by adding 4 spaces??

Comment: How about returning List<object>? but you'll have to check the type when you loop through the list...

Comment: Try using a generic function of T

Comment: list<T> GetSomeValue<T>(string id) where T : parent { ... }

Comment: @AllenZhang try reading my answer

Comment: User2012384, `List<object>` would be no better than a non-generic List. Worse, in some ways for implying some kind of generic-ness that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning different types of `List<T>` wont work since List is not `Covariant`.

You can achieve your goal by lowering your response to the Interface level that implements the `out` generic modifier which is the `IEnumerable<T>`

So in this example code mockup, it should work.

```
private static IEnumerable<Parent> Test(bool flag) // returns a covariant collection
{
    if (flag)
        return new List<Parent>(); 
    else
        return new List<Child>();
}
```

Read more about [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an interface to the classes and have your method return an interface instead of a concrete type.

However I would point out that since this is either a child or a parent, and no other logic, I would consider making it two methods to avoid the casting. It may seem like it saves code to wrap it in a single method, but keep on mind that the complexity of casting/branching is then pushed out to the caller.

Comment: Wouldn't that result in losing the child-specific properties, assuming that those properties are required for further processing?

Comment: @shree.pat18 child-specific properties are indeed required for further processing.

Comment: Add a property that differentiates the types on the interface and cast as needed.

Comment: If the methods used to do processing are named the same you can benefit from polymorphism here

Comment: @TCG does it harm to just use the parent type in the return value?

Comment: I would recommend making this two methods.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
IEnumerable<parent> GetSomeValue(string id, boolean needChild) {  
  ......  
  if (needChild)  
    return BuildChildResult(id);  
  else  
    return BuildParentResult(id);  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108922/how-do-i-convert-a-class-which-is-derived-from-a-generic-base-class-to-that

Answer (score 0):

I think an interface is the way to go. Look at this program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {
        bool needChild = true;

        IEnumerable<IMyClass> myChildList = GetSomeValue("1", needChild);
        List<Child> myChildren = myChildList.Cast<Child>().ToList();

        needChild = false;
        IEnumerable<IMyClass> myParentList = GetSomeValue("1", needChild);
        List<Parent> myParents = myParentList.Cast<Parent>().ToList();

    }

    private static IEnumerable<IMyClass> GetSomeValue(string id, bool needChild)
    {
        if (needChild)
        {
            return BuildChildResult(id);
        }

        return BuildParentResult(id);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IMyClass> BuildChildResult(string id)
    {
        var list = new List<IMyClass>
        {
            new Child {ChildName = "Test 1", Id = "1"},
            new Child {ChildName = "Test 2", Id = "1"},
            new Child {ChildName = "Test 3", Id = "1"},
            new Child {ChildName = "Test 4", Id = "2"},
            new Child {ChildName = "Test 4", Id = "2"},
            new Child {ChildName = "Test 4", Id = "3"}
        };

        return list.Where(z => z.Id == id).ToList();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IMyClass> BuildParentResult(string id)
    {
        var list = new List<IMyClass>
        {
            new Parent {ParentName = "Test 1", Id = "1"},
            new Parent {ParentName = "Test 2", Id = "1"},
            new Parent {ParentName = "Test 3", Id = "1"},
            new Parent {ParentName = "Test 4", Id = "2"},
            new Parent {ParentName = "Test 4", Id = "2"},
            new Parent {ParentName = "Test 4", Id = "3"}
        };

        return list.Where(z => z.Id == id).ToList();
    }
}

public interface IMyClass
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    bool IsParent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent : IMyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsParent { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }

    public Parent()
    {
        IsParent = true;
    }
}

public class Child : IMyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsParent { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }

    public Child()
    {
        IsParent = false;
    }
}
```

Running this will create a child list called myChildren and a parent list called myParents.

The interface only needs one property, the bool IsParent property. Through that, the GetSomeValue method can build the appropriate parent or child, then return an enumerated list, which can then be cast to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Generic as follows

```
    public static List<T> GetSomeValue<T>(string id)
    {
        return (typeof(T) == typeof(Child)) ? BuildChildResult(id) as List<T> : BuildParentResult(id) as List<T>;
    }
```

Then you can call it like

```
        var childList = GetSomeValue<Child>("");
        var parentList = GetSomeValue<Parent>("");
```